# Tufte-book with tikz-timing resulting in alignment problems

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tufte, tikz-timing

I am writing a lecture note and decided to use the tufte-book template for it. I have to include timing diagrams hence using the tikz-timing package. It seems that the combination of these two result in alignment problems in the timing diagram.

A MWE would be like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

\section{Sample Section}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tikztimingtable}
    \texttt{Clk} & 105{0.1H 0.1L} \\
    \texttt{Clk\_Divided} & 21{C}\\
    \texttt{nReset} & LL 19{H}\\
    \texttt{Digits} & 3D{0001} 2D{0010} 2D{0100} 2D{1000} 2D{0001} 2D{0010} 2D{0100} 2D{1000} 2D{0001}
  2D{0010}\\
  \end{tikztimingtable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The above code produces this layout:

[image]

But instead of this the correct timing diagram should look like this:

[image]

I would be extremely grateful if someone could provide a workaround for this.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Please can you put a screenshot of your problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: I just added a screenshot what is produced by MWE and a screenshot of the timing diagram it should appear.

Answer (score 3):

I now debugged this issue with my package `tikz-timing` under `tufte-book` class. The `tikztimingtable` sets the font to `\sffamily` by default using the `font` TikZ key but also using `/utils/exec={\sffamily}` in order to recalculate the scaling dependent on the font. These two usages of `\sffamily` clashes with `tufte-book` class. I don't know why exactly yet.

However, the problem is fixed by removing the `font=\sffamily` part by redefining the `timing/table` TikZ style.

Sidenote: If you want your signal names in texttyper style, simply set the font in `timing/name` in the preamble. No need to use `\texttt` all the time.

The following example will get you the result you want.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\tikzset{%
  timing/table/.style={timing,line width=0.15ex}, % fix tufte-book issue
  timing/name/.style={font=\ttfamily} % Signal names in tt-Font
}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

\section{Sample Section}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tikztimingtable}
    Clk & 105{0.1H 0.1L} \\
    Clk\_Divided & 21{C}\\
    nReset & LL 19{H}\\
    Digits & 3D{0001} 2D{0010} 2D{0100} 2D{1000} 2D{0001} 2D{0010} 2D{0100} 2D{1000} 2D{0001}
  2D{0010}\\
  \end{tikztimingtable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I might further investigate the font issue.

Comment: Turned out that the use of `ragged2e` by `tufte-book` causes this together with some special code used by `tikz-timing`.